# How to find the URL loaded in same page or different page of android webview?

Tags: android, webview

In My Android mobile app, I have webview and I have loaded some third party URL. The problem is that web-page have login page when press login with details entered it returns the same login page again . Is anyone, can help me how to solve this problem? or why its redirected again to same login page? or how to find the url loding in same page of webview or different page of webview?

Answer (score 0):

Add WebViewClient to your webview it will override `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` in which you get every loaded url by webResourceRequest object which have `getUrl(), getMethod()` and other methods. `getUrl()`

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest) {

       webResourceRequest.getUrl()
        // Here you will get every url which is loaded

        webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(
            WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    }
});
```